# Strategies for handling future schema changes in CloudKit

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

My understanding of CloudKit is that if the user has two devices - one with a version of the app with a v2 schema and another with a v1 schema - the device with the v1 schema will receive new data but only for the fields in v1. All new data in new fields created in schema v2 are discarded for this particular device. At a later date when the app with the v1 schema updates to the v2 schema, the new data in v2 fields made on the newer version of the app are never pulled again and the two devices have a mismatch of data.

*This understanding comes from [this blog](http://www.grantgrueninger.com/2020/01/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-in-production/) discussing NSPersistentCloudKitContainer (what I am using).*

This is clearly a problem, there can be a few days between when the first device updates an app (e.g. an iPhone) and when the second device updates an app (e.g. an iPad). What strategies can I deploy in my schema or implementation to solve this problem?

Comment: As part of your 2.0 update can you just refetch everything?

Comment: @BrianM Perhaps I'm missing something in the sparse docs, but I'm not even sure that's possible with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Comment: Sorry I had missed the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer part

Answer (score 0):

If your model doesn't have versioning, then the best practice appears to be waiting to utilize the new parts of the model until enough people have updated to it. This is assuming you're using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.

Let's say a user is on version 1 and the model for a `List` entity on their device looks like this:

```swift
@NSManaged public var dateAdded: Date?
@NSManaged public var id: String?
@NSManaged public var title: String?
```

While working version 2, you change the production model in iCloud to add a property to the `List` entity:

```swift
@NSManaged public var dateEdited: Date? //NEW
@NSManaged public var dateAdded: Date?
@NSManaged public var id: String?
@NSManaged public var title: String?
```

Their app should continue working just fine as long as you haven't implemented any features that use the new property.

Adding a completely new entity like `Notes` should have no effect on existing users in production until you actually implement a feature that uses that entity.

Waiting a few releases before using the new data model changes should allow enough time for people to update to a version that has the new model.

#### Sources

- [NSPersistentCloudKitContainer in production](http://www.grantgrueninger.com/2020/01/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-in-production/)
- [See the "Update Your Production Schema" in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/creating_a_core_data_model_for_cloudkit)